# MYSQL multiple tables multiple result for each

Tags: mysql

I'm new here so if there's something I'm doing wrong I apologize.

I'm trying to get some table result on MYSQL I have this 2 tables:

`Table_1 (id, date_from, date_to)`

`Table_2 (date, x)`

what I need to do is, for each record on Table 1 get the next result

```
(id,date_from,date_to,sum(x))
```

For example if I have this records:

Table 1:

```
1|date1|date5
2|date3|date4
3|date2|date5
```

Table 2:

```
date1|7
date2|5
date3|1
date4|4
date5|3
```

the query should show this:

```
1|date1|date5|20
2|date3|date4|5
3|date2|date5|13
```

the query I have so far doesn't work and is this:

```
Select 
  a.id, 
  a.date_from, 
  a.date_to, 
  sum(b.x) 
from table1 a 
inner join table_2 b 
on b.date >= a.date_from 
  and b.date <= a.date_to
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a.id is unique key then:

```
SELECT 
  a.id, 
  a.date_from, 
  a.date_to, 
  SUM(b.x) 
FROM table1 a 
LEFT JOIN table_2 b 
ON  b.date >= a.date_from 
  AND b.date <= a.date_to
GROUP BY a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "group by a.date_from" so that your statement becomes:

Select a.id, a.date_from, a.date_to, sum(b.x) from table1 a inner join table_2 b on b.date >= a.date_from and b.date <= a.date_to 
group by a.date_from

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.  You just need to group by the id, date_from and date_to

```
Select 
  a.id, 
  a.date_from, 
  a.date_to, 
  sum(b.x) 
from table1 a 
inner join table_2 b 
on b.date >= a.date_from 
  and b.date <= a.date_to
group by a.id, a.date_from, a.date_to
```